# Is there a class that can change their weapon's form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Is there any class in D&D 3.5e that can change its weapon's form? For example having a Longsword and changing its form to be a spear.

Comment: I know there's at least one magic item that does it (change itself, that is), would that work?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Have fun. It sounds like you have an idea of what you want the character to be able to accomplish and this is way to make it happen. Can you also explain what you want the character to accomplish?

Comment: Is it important to you that *a class feature* be the solution, or do you just want the end goal of a shapeshifting weapon?

Answer (score 6):

An arcane caster (sor/wis, spellthief, or bard) can cast the spell "Weapon Shift" (Spell Compendium p237) which:

> A weapon shift spell allows you to temporarily transform any one melee weapon into a different melee weapon.

A psychic warrior can use the power "[Call Weaponry](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/callWeaponry.htm)" which allows you to summon any weapon.

The incarnum blade can:

> create a special soulmeld called a blademeld by wrapping incarnum into a melee weapon of your choice

(and says nothing about always being that specific weapon)

Or, instead of a golfbag of weapons, you can just have your backup weapon be a "transmuting" (+2, Magic item Compendium, p45) weapon, which, after a successful hit, transforms to have all the necessary properties to overcome a creature's damage resistance for 10 rounds.

Answer (score 3):

An Artificer (Eberron Campaign Setting, p29) can spend one minute to use the level 1 infusion *Weapon Augmentation, Personal* to add the "Morphing" property (Magic Item Compendium, p39) to a weapon for a duration of 10 minutes per caster level.  A morphing weapon can be changed into any other weapon of the same size and type (light, one-handed, or two-handed) as a standard action.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [**Soulknife**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/soulknife.htm).

He doesn't so much "change his weapon's form" as he creates blades of pure energy with his mind. At 2nd level, he can throw his blades. At 5th level, he can change them into different types of weapons. He can also enchant his summoned blades with all sorts of effects, for free.

Comment: Unfortunately, the soulknife is one of the most truly atrocious classes in the game. They get a magic weapon, but everyone can get a magic weapon, and actually can get a better one than the soulknife can. Aside from that, Psychic Strike is one of the absolute worst forms of bonus damage in the game.

Comment: Without taking the feats to do so, the soulknife can't make his shortsword into anything but a longsword or bastard sword (not even, oddly, a knife).